# Find mistake in calculations of intersection multiplicity to show that two circles have empty intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I think I've made a mistake somewhere here, but I can't find it... I'm trying to show that the intersection of two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ with the same center and different radii in affine space is trivial. My idea was to take the projective closure of the two circles and show by Bezout's theorem that their intersection is 4. Then I hoped to show that the intersection multiplicities of the two circular points at infinity $[1 : i : 0]$ and $[1 : -i : 0]$ were each 2, to conclude that the projective circles only intersect on the line at infinity, and hence the two affine circles have empty intersection. But I get that each point has intersection multiplicity 4...
Can someone see what I did wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why bother with all of this? $(x^2+y^2-a,x^2+y^2-b)$ is the unit ideal when $a\neq b$. (Also, your picture is not great to read - please typeset math here using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).)

Comment: Firstly, because the exercise was to try to solve it with Bezout's theorem. And secondly, because if I have some misunderstanding about intersection multiplicities, I would like to find it so as to avoid making similar mistakes in the future.
But thanks for pointing the thing about the unit ideal out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's calculate. If our two equations are $x^2+y^2-az^2$ and $x^2+y^2-bz^2$ for $a\neq b$, then the points of intersection on the line at infinity $z=0$ are $[1:i:0]$ and $[1:-i:0]$. Dehomogenizing with respect to $x$, we're looking to calculate $\dim_{\Bbb C} \Bbb C[(y\pm i),z]_{(y\pm i,z)}/(1+y^2-az^2,1+y^2-bz^2)$. Subtracting the first polynomial from the second gives that the ideal we're quotienting by is $(1+y^2-az^2,(a-b)z^2)=(1+y^2-az^2,z^2)$, as $a\neq b$, which simplifies further to $(1+y^2,z^2)$. Changing coordinates by $y\mapsto y\mp i$, we get $$\Bbb C[y,z]_{(y,z)}/(1+y^2\mp 2iy-1,z^2)=\Bbb C[y,z]_{(y,z)}/(y^2\mp 2iy,z^2).$$
But $y^2\mp 2iy = y(y\mp 2i)$, and $(y\mp 2i)$ is a unit in $\Bbb C[y,z]_{(y,z)}$, so $(y^2\mp 2iy,z^2)=(y,z^2)\subset \Bbb C[y,z]_{(y,z)}$, so the dimension of the quotient is two, and the intersection multiplicity at each of the points at infinity is two.

Your mistake is that you didn't apply the coordinate change to your equations - your step where you "assume $P=(0,0)$" is where you went wrong. To do that, you have to move your point there by a change of coordinates, and that will affect your equations!