# Showing intersection multiplicity of circular points at infinity is two on the intersection of two concentric circles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is in regards to a previous post that is still open here: [Find mistake in calculations of intersection multiplicity to show that two circles have empty intersection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4825008/find-mistake-in-calculations-of-intersection-multiplicity-to-show-that-two-circl?noredirect=1#comment10270421_4825008)

My question is, if we have two circles in $\mathbb{P}^2$,
$\mathbb{V}(x^2 + y^2 - (z r_1)^2)$ and $\mathbb{V}(x^2 + y^2 - (z r_2)^2)$ with $r_1 \neq r_2$, how do we show that the intersection multiplicities of the two circular points at infinity on these circles is each two?
My problem is that I keep getting that each is four instead of two.

Help Would be appreciated.

Comment: You've already asked the question, no need to ask it again.